# Converting SVG lines to arcs

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

I'm using Python's svgwrite to draw an SVG diagram.  I have a bunch of horizontal lines that I'm currently drawing with Paths.  It's pretty simple, point A to point B.  I'd like to convert these lines to be slightly rounded up (the height will be some distance, say 10).  I can't figure out how to convert this though.

In other words, if I have  and I want to convert this into an arc going from (100,100)->(200,100) with a slight bend up, what would the corresponding arc command be?  Or bezier curve if that's easier?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was confusing A and a in my tests.  It's simply:

```
M100,100 A100,50 0 0 0 200,100
```